# TS2322: Type 'IEvent | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IEvent'

Tags: angular, typescript

When I assign `getEvent()` type to `IEvent`, I get this error,

> TS2322: Type 'IEvent | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IEvent'.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs"
import { IEvent } from "./event.model"

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  getEvents():Observable<IEvent[]> {
    let subject = new Subject<IEvent[]>()

    setTimeout(() => { subject.next(EVENTS); subject.complete() }, 200)
    return subject
  }

  getEvent(id: number): IEvent {
    return EVENTS.find(event => event.id === id) // Error here
  }
}
```

Comment: `find` can return `undefined` if nothing is found. What do you want to happen if that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

Add 'undefined' to your return type:

```
  getEvent(id: number): IEvent | undefined {
    return EVENTS.find(event => event.id === id) // Error here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -2):

Define the IEvent type as "any". If that doesn't fix your issue try upgrading your rxjs version.
This should fix your problem!

Comment: This quashes the error by completely defeating the reason for having a type system. Note this is not the same as specifying `| undefined` as a possible return - at least then the caller can react accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok  i will try it